# Create a scope in rails based on HABTM association count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a rails scope based on the count of a model's HABTM assocation, but I'm struggling with the SQL.

I want Match.open to return matches with less than two users. I also have Match.upcoming, which returns matches with a 'future_date' in the future, which is working well.

My code:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  scope :open, joins('matches_users').
      select('*').
      group('matches.id').
      having('count(matches_users.user_id) < 2')


scope :upcoming, lambda {
    where("proposed_date between ? and ?", Date.today, Date.today.next_month.beginning_of_month)
}
```

I'm currently getting the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: matches_users.user_id: SELECT * FROM "matches" matches_users GROUP BY matches.id HAVING count(matches_users.user_id) < 2
```

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: matches_users.user_id: SELECT * FROM "matches" matches_users GROUP BY matches.id HAVING count(matches_users.user_id) < 2

I'm currently achieving this with a class method:

```
def self.open
    self.select{|match| match.users.length < 2}
end
```

Which works, but I'd really like to move this into a scope for speed, and so that I can chain the scopes like Match.open.upcoming.

What am I doing wrong here? What's the correct way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My schema for the table matches_users:

  
    create_table "matches_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
        t.integer "match_id"
        t.integer "user_id"
    end

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot - I've used something similar before and it seems to work for me:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  scope :open, joins(:matches_users)
               .select('matches.*')
               .group('matches.id')
               .having('count(matches_users.id) < 2')

...

end
```

Comment: That looks pretty good as far as I can tell, but I get the following error:

    ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'matches_users' was not found on Match; perhaps you misspelled it?